# Nginx - variable usage (set vs map) context and usage

Tags: variables, nginx, nginx-location

In Nginx configurations,

I do not know when / where I can use `map` or `set`.

I want to do something like this:

I tried using `map`:

```
    map $host $proxy_destination_include {
        default '/etc/nginx/conf.d/params/proxy.params/proxy_params_destination.conf';
    }
```

Or tried using `set`:

```
server {
    ### I want to use this as either a variable / map ###
    set $proxy_destination_include /etc/nginx/conf.d/params/proxy.params/proxy_params_destination.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    location / {
         set_proxy_header X-Forwarded-Location-Site 'static-value';
         include $proxy_destination_include;
    }

    location /otherlocation {
         set_proxy_header X-Forwarded-Location-Site 'static-value-2';
         include $proxy_destination_include;
    }
}
```

But I think `map` can only be used when a 'site request' is done?  So since it has not been mapped Nginx cannot successfully compile its settings - `sudo nginx -t` *fails*

- Is there any way to do this using Nginx and 'variables'?